# Using Interface to add a private setter

Tags: c#, .net

I have an Interface that has only one property like below

```
public interface IExtendable
{
      Hashtable ExtendedProperties { get; set;}
}
```

I want setter to be private but it doesnt allow because its coming from an Interface and everyhing should be public in it as I know.

So what can be the best practice to allowing private setter ?

- Dont use Interface in this scenario or what ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can use an abstract class.

Comment: An interface represents the public API of an object that other classes consume. The private aspects of the class are of no concern to the consumers, so there's no reason to put it in the interface.

Comment: @Shaks an abstract class still wouldn't help because even the derived class would not be able to access a `private` member unless you make it `protected`.

Comment: @MattDavey - That's right. My bad. :(

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got the answer as I guess

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not add a private setter to an interface. If you want to have a private setter, then your interface will need to look like this:

```
public interface IExtendable 
{       
     Hashtable ExtendedProperties { get; } 
}
```

And in the implementation of the interface you can add your private setter.

Comment: +1 The outside world should not know or care about private implementation details of a class.

Answer (score 3):

```
private interface IExtendable
{
    Hashtable ExtendedProperties { get; }
}

private class Extendable: IExtendable
{
    Hashtable ExtendedProperties { get; private set; }
}
```